# Cant start whirr on ec2 - describeAvailabilityZonesInRegion(Unknown Source)

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-whirr

Below is my properties file and error.  How do I resolve?  Thanks

```
whirr.cluster-name=myhadoopcluster
whirr.instance-templates=1 hadoop-jobtracker+hadoop-namenode,2 hadoop-datanode+hadoop-tasktracker
whirr.provider=aws-ec2
whirr.private-key-file=${sys:user.home}/.ssh/id_rsa_whirr
whirr.public-key-file=${sys:user.home}/.ssh/id_rsa_whirr.pub
whirr.identity=dddd
whirr.credential=fffff
whirr.hardware-id=m3.medium
whirr.image-id=us-west-1/ami-c3888986
whirr.location-id=us-west-1 
whirr.java.install-function=install_oab_java
```

Below is my error:

```
 ~/whirr/whirr/bin/whirr launch-cluster --config ~/hadoop.properties
Running on provider aws-ec2 using identity TTTTTTT
Bootstrapping cluster
Configuring template for bootstrap-hadoop-datanode_hadoop-tasktracker
Unable to start the cluster. Terminating all nodes.
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.describeAvailabilityZonesInRegion(Unknown Source)
    at org.jclouds.ec2.suppliers.DescribeAvailabilityZonesInRegion.get(DescribeAvailabilityZonesInRegion.java:66)
    at org.jclouds.ec2.suppliers.DescribeAvailabilityZonesInRegion.get(DescribeAvailabilityZonesInRegion.java:45)
    at org.jclouds.rest.suppliers.MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier$SetAndThrowAuthorizationExceptionSupplierBackedLoader.load(MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.java:91)
    at org.jclouds.rest.suppliers.MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier$SetAndThrowAuthorizationExceptionSupplierBackedLoader.load(MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.java:72)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3589)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2374)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2337)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2252)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3990)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3994)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4878)
    at org.jclouds.rest.suppliers.MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.get(MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.java:140)
    at org.jclouds.location.suppliers.derived.ZoneIdsFromRegionIdToZoneIdsValues.get(ZoneIdsFromRegionIdToZoneIdsValues.java:52)
    at org.jclouds.location.suppliers.derived.ZoneIdsFromRegionIdToZoneIdsValues.get(ZoneIdsFromRegionIdToZoneIdsValues.java:39)
    at org.jclouds.util.Suppliers2$SupplierComposition.get(Suppliers2.java:179)
    at org.jclouds.rest.suppliers.MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier$SetAndThrowAuthorizationExceptionSupplierBackedLoader.load(MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.java:91)
    at org.jclouds.rest.suppliers.MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier$SetAndThrowAuthorizationExceptionSupplierBackedLoader.load(MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.java:72)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3589)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2374)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2337)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2252)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3990)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3994)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4878)
    at org.jclouds.rest.suppliers.MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.get(MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.java:140)
    at org.jclouds.location.suppliers.all.ZoneToRegionToProviderOrJustProvider.get(ZoneToRegionToProviderOrJustProvider.java:78)
    at org.jclouds.location.suppliers.all.ZoneToRegionToProviderOrJustProvider.get(ZoneToRegionToProviderOrJustProvider.java:52)
    at org.jclouds.rest.suppliers.MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier$SetAndThrowAuthorizationExceptionSupplierBackedLoader.load(MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.java:91)
    at org.jclouds.rest.suppliers.MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier$SetAndThrowAuthorizationExceptionSupplierBackedLoader.load(MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.java:72)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3589)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2374)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2337)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2252)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3990)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3994)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4878)
    at org.jclouds.rest.suppliers.MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.get(MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.java:140)
    at org.jclouds.compute.domain.internal.TemplateBuilderImpl.locationId(TemplateBuilderImpl.java:590)
    at org.jclouds.compute.domain.TemplateBuilderSpec.copyTo(TemplateBuilderSpec.java:287)
    at org.jclouds.compute.domain.internal.TemplateBuilderImpl.from(TemplateBuilderImpl.java:1089)
    at org.apache.whirr.compute.BootstrapTemplate.build(BootstrapTemplate.java:74)
    at org.apache.whirr.actions.BootstrapClusterAction.doAction(BootstrapClusterAction.java:101)
    at org.apache.whirr.actions.ScriptBasedClusterAction.execute(ScriptBasedClusterAction.java:131)
    at org.apache.whirr.ClusterController.bootstrapCluster(ClusterController.java:137)
    at org.apache.whirr.ClusterController.launchCluster(ClusterController.java:113)
    at org.apache.whirr.cli.command.LaunchClusterCommand.run(LaunchClusterCommand.java:69)
    at org.apache.whirr.cli.command.LaunchClusterCommand.run(LaunchClusterCommand.java:59)
    at org.apache.whirr.cli.Main.run(Main.java:69)
    at org.apache.whirr.cli.Main.main(Main.java:102)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout waiting for task.
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:264)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:96)
    at org.jclouds.concurrent.ExceptionParsingListenableFuture.get(ExceptionParsingListenableFuture.java:76)
    at org.jclouds.concurrent.internal.SyncProxy.invoke(SyncProxy.java:170)
    ... 50 more
Unable to load cluster state, assuming it has no running nodes.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/ubuntu/.whirr/myhadoopcluster/instances (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at com.google.common.io.Files$1.getInput(Files.java:109)
    at com.google.common.io.Files$1.getInput(Files.java:106)
    at com.google.common.io.CharStreams$2.getInput(CharStreams.java:93)
    at com.google.common.io.CharStreams$2.getInput(CharStreams.java:90)
    at com.google.common.io.CharStreams.readLines(CharStreams.java:307)
    at com.google.common.io.Files.readLines(Files.java:543)
    at org.apache.whirr.state.FileClusterStateStore.load(FileClusterStateStore.java:55)
    at org.apache.whirr.state.ClusterStateStore.tryLoadOrEmpty(ClusterStateStore.java:59)
    at org.apache.whirr.ClusterController.destroyCluster(ClusterController.java:226)
    at org.apache.whirr.ClusterController.launchCluster(ClusterController.java:121)
    at org.apache.whirr.cli.command.LaunchClusterCommand.run(LaunchClusterCommand.java:69)
    at org.apache.whirr.cli.command.LaunchClusterCommand.run(LaunchClusterCommand.java:59)
    at org.apache.whirr.cli.Main.run(Main.java:69)
    at org.apache.whirr.cli.Main.main(Main.java:102)
Finished running destroy phase scripts on all cluster instances
Destroying myhadoopcluster cluster
Cluster myhadoopcluster destroyed
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.apache.whirr.ClusterController.launchCluster(ClusterController.java:128)
    at org.apache.whirr.cli.command.LaunchClusterCommand.run(LaunchClusterCommand.java:69)
    at org.apache.whirr.cli.command.LaunchClusterCommand.run(LaunchClusterCommand.java:59)
    at org.apache.whirr.cli.Main.run(Main.java:69)
    at org.apache.whirr.cli.Main.main(Main.java:102)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.describeAvailabilityZonesInRegion(Unknown Source)
    at org.jclouds.ec2.suppliers.DescribeAvailabilityZonesInRegion.get(DescribeAvailabilityZonesInRegion.java:66)
    at org.jclouds.ec2.suppliers.DescribeAvailabilityZonesInRegion.get(DescribeAvailabilityZonesInRegion.java:45)
    at org.jclouds.rest.suppliers.MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier$SetAndThrowAuthorizationExceptionSupplierBackedLoader.load(MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.java:91)
    at org.jclouds.rest.suppliers.MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier$SetAndThrowAuthorizationExceptionSupplierBackedLoader.load(MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.java:72)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3589)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2374)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2337)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2252)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3990)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3994)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4878)
    at org.jclouds.rest.suppliers.MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.get(MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.java:140)
    at org.jclouds.location.suppliers.derived.ZoneIdsFromRegionIdToZoneIdsValues.get(ZoneIdsFromRegionIdToZoneIdsValues.java:52)
    at org.jclouds.location.suppliers.derived.ZoneIdsFromRegionIdToZoneIdsValues.get(ZoneIdsFromRegionIdToZoneIdsValues.java:39)
    at org.jclouds.util.Suppliers2$SupplierComposition.get(Suppliers2.java:179)
    at org.jclouds.rest.suppliers.MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier$SetAndThrowAuthorizationExceptionSupplierBackedLoader.load(MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.java:91)
    at org.jclouds.rest.suppliers.MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier$SetAndThrowAuthorizationExceptionSupplierBackedLoader.load(MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.java:72)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3589)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2374)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2337)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2252)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3990)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3994)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4878)
    at org.jclouds.rest.suppliers.MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.get(MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.java:140)
    at org.jclouds.location.suppliers.all.ZoneToRegionToProviderOrJustProvider.get(ZoneToRegionToProviderOrJustProvider.java:78)
    at org.jclouds.location.suppliers.all.ZoneToRegionToProviderOrJustProvider.get(ZoneToRegionToProviderOrJustProvider.java:52)
    at org.jclouds.rest.suppliers.MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier$SetAndThrowAuthorizationExceptionSupplierBackedLoader.load(MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.java:91)
    at org.jclouds.rest.suppliers.MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier$SetAndThrowAuthorizationExceptionSupplierBackedLoader.load(MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.java:72)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3589)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2374)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2337)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2252)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3990)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3994)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4878)
    at org.jclouds.rest.suppliers.MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.get(MemoizedRetryOnTimeOutButNotOnAuthorizationExceptionSupplier.java:140)
    at org.jclouds.compute.domain.internal.TemplateBuilderImpl.locationId(TemplateBuilderImpl.java:590)
    at org.jclouds.compute.domain.TemplateBuilderSpec.copyTo(TemplateBuilderSpec.java:287)
    at org.jclouds.compute.domain.internal.TemplateBuilderImpl.from(TemplateBuilderImpl.java:1089)
    at org.apache.whirr.compute.BootstrapTemplate.build(BootstrapTemplate.java:74)
    at org.apache.whirr.actions.BootstrapClusterAction.doAction(BootstrapClusterAction.java:101)
    at org.apache.whirr.actions.ScriptBasedClusterAction.execute(ScriptBasedClusterAction.java:131)
    at org.apache.whirr.ClusterController.bootstrapCluster(ClusterController.java:137)
    at org.apache.whirr.ClusterController.launchCluster(ClusterController.java:113)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout waiting for task.
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:264)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:96)
    at org.jclouds.concurrent.ExceptionParsingListenableFuture.get(ExceptionParsingListenableFuture.java:76)
    at org.jclouds.concurrent.internal.SyncProxy.invoke(SyncProxy.java:170)
    ... 50 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It does work using the previous generation instance type:

> whirr.hardware-id=m1.medium